# WiFi adapter disconnects until reboot

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver

I have a combo WiFi/Bluetooth PCIe card installed in my PC (tower PC I built).  I don't recall the specific make or model, but it's running using Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 driver.

The adapter will work when the PC is first started.  It connects to WiFi just fine, but after some period of time (never the same, sometimes minutes, sometimes hours), it loses its ability to see any WiFi access spots.  At that point, I can see from my laptop (separate PC) that there are at least 15 WiFi networks within range at a mid to high level quality of signal, but the PC still can't pick them up.

I've updated the drivers for the PCIe card.  I've ensured all updates for Windows are installed.  I've disabled/enabled the card.  I even did the Windows 10 "refresh PC" thing to see if there was some other software hosing things up.  None of that worked.

The only fix I've found is rebooting the PC.

Anyone have any ideas or seen this before?

Comment: Sounds like a power save issue look for the 'allow this device to turn off to save power's or similar  in the device properties

Comment: Interesting! I'll need to check this out! Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the following reasons:

1. The hardware is not compatible.
2. There is a problem with The combo WiFi/Bluetooth PCIe card.
3. Insufficient power supply.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've had this card working for over a year in this PC. So I believe it's compatible and it would seem the power supply should be alright as well. I'm thinking maybe sooner if the circuitry went bad on the card??